# Drawing a simple square in webgl

Tags: webgl

I have a very basic question. I am new to webgl and trying to draw a simple square. I am using the gl matrix library for matrix manipulation.

Javascript Code:

```
squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    vertices = [
         0.9,  0.9,  0.0,1.0,
        -0.9,  0.9,  0.0,1.0,
         0.9, -0.9,  0.0,1.0,
        -0.9, -0.9,  0.0,1.0

    ];


    squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;

    mat4.identity(pMatrix);
    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,         squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
```

Shader:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec3 debug;


void main(void) {
    gl_Position =  uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition.xyz, 1.0);
    debug = aVertexPosition;
}
```

This seems to work out fine.Here i am passing the model view and perspective matrices as uniforms to the shader programs and multiplying them with the vertex coordinates there. But if multiply the model view and perspective matrices in the javascript and the then pass the modified vertices to the shader, it doesnt seem to work.

I'm not able to spot the mistake. Help highly appreciated!

Comment: If you're trying to draw 2D check out http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/  There's no need to use a modelview and projection matrix for 2D.

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat I notice a couple issues:

1) Your vertex shader input attribute does not match the parameters passed to vertexAttribPointer:

You specify that the attribute is 4 floats wide but your vertex shader specifies it as a vec3. These should be consistent.

2) I don't see a call to enableVertexAttribArray, something like:

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

You must enable the vertex attribute arrays that your vertex shader uses.

3) From the code shown- you are only specifying a model matrix (identity, translate). You need to create a view matrix. An easy way to do that is to call mat4.lookAt. It has the following definition:

mat4.lookAt = function (eye, center, up, dest)

eye is the position of the camera
center is the position the camera is looking at
up should always be (0, 1, 0)

An example would be:

eye = (0, 0, 1)
center = (0, 0, 0)

That puts the camera 1 unit down the positive Z axis and has it looking at the origin.

Multiplying this with your model matrix will give you a modelview matrix.

---

There is so much code missing that it makes it difficult to determine if your mistake lies somewhere else. For example, what does your fragment shader do?

---

When trying to get your first primitive on the screen, I recommend disabling culling and depth testing. Also vary your clear color over time in case your fragment output matches the clear color.

John

Comment: It's convenient for us humans to use separate model and view matrices, but GL doesn't care at all. In the old days, the only GL matrices were the ModelView concatenation and the Projection. Now, with programmable shaders, it doesn't make any difference. He could use quaternions for all GL cares; as long as the correct values make their way into `gl_Position` it's all good. Personally, I program with separate Model, View and Projection matrices, but premultiply them into a single MVP whenever I can. Also, the fragment code shouldn't matter for this issue because it can't alter pixel position.

Comment: There's no need for attributes and vertexAttribPointer to match. GL provides defaults for any values you don't supply. x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 1 by default so if you use vec4 in your code and only supply vec3 with vertexAttribPointer it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issues outlined in John's answer are worth looking into, but if you're getting the primitive to render properly now then I don't think they are the root cause of this problem.

I've split my answer into two segments since I'm not sure which scenario applies to you:

- You didn't show how you are constructing the JavaScript version of the MVP, but double check that your multiplication syntax is correct. It should be of the form:

  ```
  mat4.multiply(p, mv, mvp);
  ```

  where `p` is the projection matrix, `mv` is the modelview matrix, and `mvp` is the receiving modelview projection matrix (where the result will be stored).
- Similarly, if you are premultiplying the vertex positions themselves, the correct syntax is:

  ```
  mat4.multiplyVec4(mvp, vertex, transformedVertex);
  ```

  where `mvp` is the modelview projection matrix, `vertex` is the unmodified vertex (a `vec4`), and `transformedVertex` is a receiving `vec4` where the values will be stored. If you use this approach, you'll have to flatten an array of vertices into a single contiguous array of floats before sending them to the GPU.

  Be careful not to confuse `mat4.multiplyVec3` with `mat4.multiplyVec4`. The fourth component of `vertex` should be set to `1` prior to multiplication; this way, the fourth component of `transformedVertex` can be used by the GPU to perform perspective division (this happens automatically but you need to send the correct values).

  Note also that if you send `vec3` attributes down to the GPU by mistake and the attribute is actually of type `vec4`, the 4th component defaults to 1.0. This is often convenient, but can also lead to tricky bugs if you're premultiplying these values in JavaScript. As John says, try to keep the shader definitions consistent with the JavaScript side; this will lead to less confusion in the long run.